# Matplotlib: Creating a zoomed_inset_axis with different spines than the parent axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a plot with a zoomed_inset_axis object, as seen in e.g.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_images/sphx_glr_inset_locator_demo2_001.png

Now i want my parent axes object to be despined in a certain way, so the right spine is not visible. If i do that though, my zoomed inset is also despined in the same way, which i do not want. I assume that happens because it has the axes object as a parent.

Is there any way to change that? Basically i want a despined parent object and a zoomed inset that i surrounded by a "normal" box.

I tried `seabon.despine(fig=fig, ax=ax)`, but that also despined my zoomed in object.
I also tried `ax.spines['right'].set_visible=False`, but that also despined my zoomed object

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 7, loc=4)
seaborn.despine(fig=fig,ax=ax, offset=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the following work as expected:

#### seaborn's despine

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, .5, loc=4)

sns.despine(ax=ax, offset=10)

plt.show()
```

#### matplotlib's spine visibility

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, .5, loc=4)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```